# Using a while loop to get root 2 using an iterative formula

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to use a while loop to calculate the value of root 2 using the formula

$x_{k+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}(x_k + dfrac{2}{x_k}$

until $abs(x_{k+1}-\sqrt(2))$<0.0001.

So far I have written the following code:

```
n=1
iteration=0.5*(n+(2/n))
while abs(iteration-(2**0.5))>=0.0001:
    n=n+1

print iteration
```

The reason I started with n=1 is because my initial error was that n was not defined for 'iteration'. I then assign the iteration formula to the variable 'iteration'. I then say that while the absolute value of the iteration formula minus root 2 is greater than or equal to 0.0001, keep using the iteration formula with a larger value of n each time.

I know this is wrong because I don't want to just use a larger value of n, but I want to use the value of the iteration from the previous result.

With this I get 1.5 printed loads of times, and I think it enters an infinite loop.

I am new to Python.

Comment: Are you sure your language doesn't interpret $a/b$ with $a$ and $b$ integers as *integer* (truncating) division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not update the value you are intested in, you just increment `n` by one.

I think you should not test for the difference of your result to the real solution.
If you need to do the calculation like this, you usually do not know the solution. Instead you should test for *convergence*. So test if the change of two following iterations is small:

```
def iterate(k):
    return 0.5 * (k + (2.0 / k))

n = 0
k = 1
k_1 = iterate(k)
while abs(k_1 - k) > 1e-4:
    k = k_1
    k_1 = iterate(k)
    n += 1 

print('convergence after {} iterations'.format(n))
print('sqrt(2) = {:1.4f}'.format(k_1))
```

result: `sqrt(2) = 1.4142`

Answer (score 1):

You define `iteration` only once. Its value does not get updated. Use a function call:

```
def iteration(n):
  return 0.5 * (n + (2 / n))
n = 1
current = iteration(n)
sqrt_2 = 2 ** 0.5  # won't be calculated for each iteration now
while abs(current - sqrt_2) >= 0.0001:
  n += 1
  current = iteration(n)
print current
```